# How to hide lines between rows in JQGrid TreeGrid

Tags: css, jqgrid

How do you hide the lines between a JQGrid TreeGrid?

I've tried:

```
<table id="TreeGrid" style="border-bottom: 0px none;border-right: 0px none;">
    </table>
```

But that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured this out for now:

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.ui-row-ltr td { border-bottom-style: none; border-right-style: none;}
```

I'm still not sure how to specify the style just for the #TreeGrid...

Finally settled on

```
#TreeGrid td { border-bottom-style: none; border-right-style: none;}
```